# I have to make fields editable in a .tpl file

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP program that I took over from another person. This is part of a code in the program that makes the field editable:

```
<td class='none'>
<?php
    if($repair[0]['description'] == "")
    {
        echo "<input class='width' id='description' value=\"" . $repair[0]['description'] . "\">";
    }
    else
    {
?>
<div id='descriptionDiv'>
    <a href="javascript:changeDiv('descriptionDiv', 'descriptionDiv2')" title='klik om te wijzigen' class='edit'><?php echo $repair[0]['description']; ?></a>
</div>
<div id='descriptionDiv2' style='display=none'>
    <input class='width' id='description' value="<?php echo $repair[0]['description']; ?>">
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
</td>
```

To understand this much better, look at the image:

[image]

The blue fields are editable.

There is a file with *.tpl extension and I have a view.php file with the following code:

```
<?php 

public function renderShowInspectionDocument()
    {
        setLastPage();
        
        $dochtml = '';
        
        //Verwijder alles totdat je een '/' tegenkomt (begin rechts). Hiermee verwijder je eventueel de 'index.php' in de url.
        $url = str_replace(end(explode('/', $_SERVER['SOMETHING'])), '', $_SERVER['SOMETHING']);
        //Template
        $template = file_get_contents('templates/inspectionDetails.tpl');
        
        if(isset($this->data['SJB']))
        {
            $SJB = $this->data['SJB'];  
            
            $dochtml .= '<tr>';
                    $dochtml .= '<td class="label">Inspecton:</td>';
                    $dochtml .= '<td><div style="width:420px; font-weight:normal; border-left:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:5px;">'. nl2br($SJB['inspection_requirement']) .'</div></td>';
                $dochtml .= '</tr>';
                $dochtml .= '<tr>';
                    $dochtml .= '<td class="label">Inspection-Tools:</td>';
                    $dochtml .= '<td><div style="width:420px; font-weight:normal; border-left:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:5px;">'. nl2br($SJB['inspection_resources']) .'</div></td>';
                $dochtml .= '</tr>';
                if(isset($SJB['extra_document']) && !empty($SJB['extra_document']))
                {
                    $dochtml .= '<tr>';
                        $dochtml .= '<td class="label">Extra document:</td>';
                        $dochtml .= '<td><a target="_blank" href="'. $url .'uploads/SJB/'. urlencode($SJB['extra_document']) .'">'. $SJB['extra_document'] .'</a></td>';
                    $dochtml .= '</tr>';
                }
                $dochtml .= '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';

        }
        
?>
```

and the .tpl has:

```
<div class="navigation" id="navigationDiv">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    table td {
        border: none;
    }
</style>

<table class="clean">
    {data}
    <tr style="display:{display};">
        <td class="label">Special:</td>
        <td>{notices}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

{back}
```

look at the image:
[image]

I want to be able to make those fields also editable but I need help with that maybe someone can help?

FOR SOME REASON THE IMAGES ARE NOT LOADING!!

Comment: Any js code you want to share?

Comment: No there is no js code, I am only working with php.

Comment: What is this `javascript:changeDiv('descriptionDiv', 'descriptionDiv2');`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 ITS THE ONLY PIECE OF JAVASCRIPT THAT I have in my code!!